# Basic Breakout Scaling Maths

Tags: javascript, math, physics

I'm currently working on a breakout game, and I got stuck on a maths problem. Here's the scenario.

The ball has a horizontal speed, named bxspd.
The ball has a X coordinate named, bx.
The ball has a maximum speed, named bspd.
The bat has x coordinates, named px.

When the ball collides with the bat, it needs to bounce off in a horizontal direction relative to the bat's position. So in other words:

//Collision Event
bxspd = bx - px.

This way, when the ball hits the left side of the bat, the ball bounces off to the left. The further it is to the left of the bat's center, the faster it's horizontal speed becomes to the left.

The problem with this is my bat has a width of 50 to each side from the center. How do I scale this to the max speed of the ball? So in other words that if it hits the utmost left corner of the bat the bxspd becomes -2 instead of -50?

Regards,
Claris

Comment: Upon writing this question, I somehow managed to figure it out. The px origin is the left of the bat, so I devised the following formula: bdx = ((bx - (px + (pwidth / 2))) / (pwidth / 2)) * bspd;

Comment: Feel free to delete the question then

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion mplungjan. I think it would be more profitable to write the formula as an answer to the question so that people can use it as a reference if they have the same question.

Comment: Sure, by all means. It did seem very localised to your issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing the question, something somehow clicked in place, so here's the solution for those who need it.

bdx = ((bx - (px + (pwidth / 2))) / (pwidth / 2)) * bspd;

bdx is the ball's xspeed.
bx is the ball's xposition.
px is the bat's xposition.
pwidth is the bat's width.
bspd is the ball's maximum speed variable, so the bdx is calculate relative to the maximum ball speed (bspd).

Please note, this formula works with an offset too. Reason being that the player's X is at the left-most side of the bat. So to find the center we add pwidth / 2 to the x of the player to find the center.

Comment: Do you have independent maximum speeds for x and y?

Comment: I hope I'm not misinterpreting your question, but here goes. bspd is defaulted to 2 when the game starts. This number limits your ball xspeed to 2, as well as the yspeed to 2, not their combined speed. Let me know if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: But then a ball flying diagonally can fly with a speed of 2.82, does this not feel weird? In my understanding you should limit the absolute speed and not x- and y-axis independently

Comment: That's indeed a good observation, I still need to figure out how I'm going to be doing that. I'm used to using GameMaker Studio where there's a built-in variable named speed, so limiting the absolute speed is as simple as "speed = min(speed, maxspeed);". Any pointers to get me going in the right direction?

Comment: I never used GameMaker Studio, so i can't help you with this. But my strategy for each tick would be to apply all accelerations and then check if the resulting speed is above the max. If it is, reduce it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say if the ball hits the outer right edge of the bat, then it gets an additional speed of `extrabatspeed`, in the center it gets 0 and on the left it gets `-extrabatspeed`. The bat has a width of `batwidth` and it collides with the ball at `batcollisionx`, with a value between 0 and `batwidth`. I assume the x-axis goes from left to right.

Then you can calculate the change in `ballspeedx` as `2 * extrabatspeed * ballcollisionx / batwidth - extrabatspeed`.

On collision `ballspeedy` becomes negative.

Capping the ball-speed should happen afterwards. Calculate the speed as `sqrt(x^2 + y^2)` and correct both x and y by the same factor.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I managed to create a formula after I posted the question. Your maths is a lot easier to read though, so I'll keep it in mind for next time.